# XSLT: select all elements without subtree

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I try to transform Doxygen XML into a text output with XSLT. Doxygen returns this XML structure:

```
<detaileddescription>
    <para>a long text with <formula id="6">$ \LaTeX $</formula> code</para>
    <para>
        <simplesect kind="see">
            <para>
                <ulink url="url">url description</ulink>
            </para>
        </simplesect>
    </para>    
</detaileddescription>
```

I try to select only that `para` node that does not contain the `simplesect` node or any other "complex tree structure".
I try this XPath:

```
detaileddescription/para/node()
```

but this will also return the `simplesect/para` node.
So, how can I select only the `para` node that does neither contain a `text()` node nor a `formula` node as a sibling?

Comment: To select `para` that does not contain `simplesect`, you can use `/detaileddescription/para[not(simplesect)]`. I am not sure what you mean by "*any other "complex tree structure".*"

Comment: What `para` node/element do you exactly want to select?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `detaileddescription/para/node()` does not select the `simplesect/para` node. It selects the `simplesect` element, but does not select its children. I think your confusion is about what happens *after* you select a node. You haven't shown us what you do with the selected nodes, but if for example you apply the `xsl:copy-of` instruction to the selected nodes, that will copy not only the selected nodes but all their children and descendants as well.

If you want a node to appear in the output without its children also appearing, then it's not enough to select the node, you need to transform it (specifically, to create a copy of the node that excludes its children).

Answer (score 0):

An XPath to get only the `ulink` node would be

```
//para[count(descendant::*) &lt; 2 and  count(text()) = 0]
```

A full XSLT-1.0 to achieve this is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="//para[count(descendant::*) &lt; 2 and  count(text()) = 0]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<para>
    <ulink url="url">url description</ulink>
</para>
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot, I use for the match expression:

    `para[count(descendant::*) &gt; 0 and count(text()) &gt; 0]`

because I would like to get the node 

    `<para>a long text with <formula id="6">$ \LaTeX $</formula> code</para>`

So I need a text-node always and if there exists the formula-nodes.

Comment: @Phil Please show a complete XSLT stylesheet in the question, together with the text output you expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote *para node that does not contain ... any ... complex tree structure*.

Then do as you wrote:

- Write a template matching `para`.
- Read (direct) child text nodes, but only containing "real" text
  (not empty ones).
- Then check whether you actually got something.
- If yes (your `para` contains some not empty text (forgetting about
  "deeper" located text nodes)), execute an identity transform.
- Otherwise your `para` will not be rendered.

Below you have a complete solution. I added `strip-space` to avoid empty output rows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="para">
    <xsl:variable name="txt" select="text()[normalize-space()]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$txt">
      <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```